# How to make menu portion of background image less transparent

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a large background image. The menu and main content portions are 900px and centered. Rather than just fill the menu background with a color, I'd like to simply blur the background image. I'd also like the blurred part to move appropriately when the page is resized so I can't just blur a section of the background. How is the best way to achieve this? I tried putting a semi-transparent .png as the background to my menu div but that didn't work, I didn't see any effect. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

The site that inspired the question is this one: http://www.bluespooncoffee.com

Comment: Wow, someone gave me a down vote without even saying why. Nice. Look, this is obviously a beginner question, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably because has no code nor any sign you attempted to do anything. You wrote that you did but there are no jsfiddle nor any code pieces that shows your attempt. SO isn't a `I need dis, pls gib me code`, it's something we try fix and explain why your attempt didn't succeeded

Comment: Well, the page background is 1 image, the background of the menu is another, semi-transparent. If you right-click an element then select "inspect element" (google chrome), you an see the dom, styles and attached events of any html element. You may also inspect javascript etc. Without seeing your failing code sample,one really cant advise on how to change it. Ctrl-Shift-I will bring up the debugger in Chrome, FireFox and Opera, in IE it's F12. Its pretty easy to mimic/copy layout/function from sites in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MAbpx/

`background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);`

This makes the background of something semi transparent because the last value is the alpha (transparency value). Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that was the ticket.